# Django South data migration is running twice

Tags: django, django-south

I have a migration:

```
    ...

def forwards(self, orm):
    for p in products.models.Product.objects.all():
        new = cart.models.Product(title = p.title)
        new.save()

    def backwards():
        ...
```

But when I run migrate it runs through the loop twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do you have

```
no_dry_run = True
```

in the migration definition?

besides, I think you should be using `orm.Product.objects.all()`

Answer (score 5):

This happens because South run twice: first time it not touch DB, second time push changes to db.

Fast solution run `./manage migrate your_app --db-dry-run`

Or use

`if not db.dry_run:`

in your code in forward/backward sections

discussed here http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/138